# Android: GPS in Background Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, background, gps, handler

After a long internet research I have not found a solution for my problem :-(

I created a BroadcastReceiver with an Alarm. The onReceive will be triggered every time the alarm will fire.

In this class I want to check the GPS values and log the new GPS values.

For not blocking the Main Thread I want to have the GPS running on the HandlerThread.

Anyway my class is not working... Maybe anyone of you can help me get it running? :-)

```
public class GPSController extends SensorTimeController {

private static final int INIT_GPS   = 1;
private static final int KILL_GPS   = 2;

// are these there?
private boolean isKilled;
private boolean finished = false;

// sensor data
private double Longitude = -1, Latitude = -1, Altitude = -1, Speed, Bearing;

// for GPS
private LocationManager manager;
private LocationReceiver mReceiver;
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
private Handler mHandler;

public GPSController(GPSModule module){
    super(module);
}

private boolean initialize(Context context){
    try{
        mReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
        manager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // check if there is some GPS
        try{
            LocationProvider gps = manager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (gps != null){
                mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("GPSSensorThread");
                mHandlerThread.start();
                mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper(), new GPSSensorHandler());
                return true;
            }else
                return false;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SensorRecord record = new SensorRecord(module.getNextIndex(), date , structure);

    if(!initialize(context))
        return;

    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(INIT_GPS));

    while(!finished){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    mHandlerThread.quit();
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("GPSSensorThread");
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper(), new GPSSensorHandler());
    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(KILL_GPS));

    while(!isKilled) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(Longitude != -1)
        record.addData("longitude", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    else
        record.addData("longitude", " ");

    if(Latitude != -1)
        record.addData("latitude", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    else
        record.addData("latitude", " ");

    if(Altitude != -1)
        record.addData("altitude", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    else
        record.addData("altitude", " ");

    if(Bearing != 0L)
        record.addData("bearing", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    else
        record.addData("bearing", " ");

    if(Speed != 0L)
        record.addData("speed", String.valueOf(Longitude));
    else
        record.addData("speed", " ");

    mHandlerThread.quit();

    module.log(record);
}

private class GPSSensorHandler implements Handler.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case INIT_GPS:
                try{
                    if (manager != null) {
                        mHandlerThread.quit();
                        mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("GPSSensorThread");
                        mHandlerThread.start();

                        // request location updates
                        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, (float) 0, mReceiver, mHandlerThread.getLooper());
                        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, (float) 0, mReceiver, mHandlerThread.getLooper());
                    }
                }catch(SecurityException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case KILL_GPS:
                if (manager!=null)
                    try{
                        manager.removeUpdates(mReceiver);
                    }catch(SecurityException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                isKilled = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

private class LocationReceiver implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null){
            Longitude   = location.getLongitude();
            Latitude    = location.getLatitude();
            Altitude    = location.getAltitude();

            // don't do anything if we get a null reading for some reason
            if (Longitude == 0.0f && Latitude == 0.0f)
                return;

            // any speed information?
            if (location.hasSpeed())
                Speed       = (double)location.getSpeed();

            // any bearing information?
            if (location.hasBearing())
                Bearing     = (double)location.getBearing();

            finished = true;
        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }
}
```

}